# Can I find item on database with given array of string but using partial string?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model `Product` with `name` and `category`

On seed:

```
Product.create(name: "apple", category: "food")
Product.create(name: "biogesic", category: "medicine")
```

And a 2 dimensional array:

```
[[1, "tray of apple", 150.00], [1, "box of ballpen", 70.30]]
```

What I need is to get if the string inside the array contains or is on the table/database `Product`

Here's what I'm thinking but I'm lost:

```
isProduct = Product.where("name like ?", "%an apple%").first
```

Where `"%apple%"` is supposed to be the string on `array`, but with that code it is limited for 1 word only.

I don't need the product `id`, I just need it if it is on the `Product` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a certain way, this can be accomplished with the Regular Expression Operator `~` for PostgreSQL and/or `REGEXP` for MySQL:

```
regex = array.flat_map { |_, sentence, _| sentence.split }.join('|')
Product.exists?(['name ~ ?', regex])
Product.exists?(['name REGEXP ?', regex])
```

Which produces:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE (name ~ 'tray|of|apple|box|of|ballpen') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

As it searches for the presence of every single word within the sentences *tray of apple* and/or *box of ballpen*.

So, in case you have a record like:

```
Product.new(name: 'tray of apple and box of ballpen')
```

It'll cover the query and return true.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I'm using MySQL so I've tried replacing '~' to 'like' and it worked. I put it on if statement but its going on else which supposed to be true.

Comment: How wrong I am. I've realised when you let me run `Product.pluck(:name)` there's no apple on my `Product` when I add it, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!